# Simultaneous play and record

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm new to iOS development, and was wondering how you could record a sound and play a sound at the same time. Im using an AVAudioPlayer and an AVAudioRecorder, but can't seem to use them together. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer guys:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *err = nil;
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
[session setActive:YES error:&err];
```

Comment: I am using the same code and `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` on `AVAudioSession` and everything is working fine except one thing the volume level of playback sound is very low. Any suggestions on this? If any please provide as soon as possible.